# "Kummer congruences" for representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$
$\newcommand{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}}$
$\newcommand{\Rep}{\operatorname{Rep}}$

First, recall the classical Kummer congruences for Bernoulli numbers: If $h \equiv k \not\equiv 0 \bmod{p^n(p-1)}$ then
\begin{equation}
(1-p^{h-1}) \frac{B_h}{h} \equiv (1-p^{k-1})\frac{B_k}{k} \bmod{p^{n+1}}.
\end{equation}

This establishes a sort of $p$-adic continuity which is what Kubota and Leopoldt use to construct their first $p$-adic $L$-function.

I was thinking about $\F_p$-representations of the finite group $G = \Z/p\Z \rtimes (\Z/p\Z)^\times$ where the action of the right on the left is by multiplication. Let $V$ be the $2$-dimensional $\F_p$-representation of $G$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(b, u) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}u & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \in \text{GL}_2(\F_p).
\end{equation}

I noticed that in the $\F_p$-representation ring of $G$, $\Rep(G, \F_p)$, the symmetric powers of $V$ satisfy some type of "$p$-adic continuity": If $h \equiv k \bmod{p^n(p-1)}$ then
\begin{equation}
\Sym^h V \equiv \Sym^k V \bmod{p^{n-1}\F_p[G]}.
\end{equation}

Is there a way to "$p$-adically interpolate" these symmetric powers? Can we give any meaning to $\Sym^aV$ for a $p$-adic integer $a$?

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_p[G]$ has characteristic $p$ can you state precisely what you mean with $Sym^h V \equiv Sym^k V \bmod{p^{n-1}\Bbb{F}_p[G]}$

Comment: @reuns The congruence is stated in the representation ring, which does not have characteristic $p$. Addition in the representation ring corresponds to direct sum of representations, so $p^n\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ means $\mathbb{F}_p[G]^{\oplus p^n}$.

Comment: No idea of what you mean $\Bbb{F}_p[G]$ has characteristic $p$ and the symmetric powers of a $\Bbb{F}_p$-representation are $\Bbb{F}_p$-representations so their traces are in $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure what the traces have to do with anything. I'm not looking at the character ring, I'm looking at the representation ring whose elements are formal differences of isomorphism classes of finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$-representations of $G$. That ring does not have characteristic $p$.